# Get average time from dataGridView

Tags: c#, time, average

I have a dataGridView that is populated from an SQL statement. It is placed in a tabcontrol and in another tabcontrol, I have different textboxes that give some insight into the figures.

Anyway, the last column is filled with duration times which are in this format:

00:03:00

What I need to do is calculate the average of the times. Everything that I have found will calculate the average of regular integers and such but not time.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried? What exactly are you having problems with? Time comparison in C#?

Comment: Can you post any code examples?

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the values to `TimeSpan`, convert them to milliseconds (or ticks), compute the average (from "regular integers"), then convert the average back to a `TimeSpan`.

Say you have those values in an array of strings called `durations`, here's what you can do with it:

```
var averageTicks = durations.Select(d => TimeSpan.Parse(d).Ticks).Average();
var averageDuration = TimeSpan.FromTicks(averageTicks);
```

Hope this helps :)